# Getting records of specific type

Tags: c#, types, visual-studio-2013, poco, entity-framework-6

I have two classes:

```
public class BaseItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ChildItem> Children { get; set; }
}
public class ChildItem : BaseItem
{
    public virtual BaseItem Parent { get; set; }
    public ChildItem() { }
}
```

And I created a DBContext plus two DBSets for these two classes. Basically, BaseItem is the root class with a tree of child items below it. The DB will contain dozens of such trees.
The Entity Framework will create just one table for both classes, which I don't like but for now it's good enough. (Can I tell EF to split it up in two tables in an easy way?)

My problem is selecting just the root items, thus anything of class BaseItem but not of class ChildItem. Something like

```
db.Items.Where(i=>i.GetType()==typeof(BaseItem))
```

Which will not work because EF can't convert the GetType method to something that makes sense to the database. So I either put a `.ToList()` before the Where-clause or I find a better solution.
Since I don't want to retrieve all 1,000,000 records before filtering out the 500 root items, I need the better solution. What would be the better solution?

This is how the DBContext (db variable) and DBSet (Items property of db) is defined.

```
 public class Datamodel : DbContext
    {
        public Datamodel() : base("name=Datamodel") { }
        public virtual DbSet<BaseItem> Items { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ChildItem> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I managed to create separate tables by adding something like `[Table("Items", Schema = "Datamodel")]` to each class. So, that's not a real issue, although I have to decide what I prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inheritance is involved, there is probably a type descriminator against the entities you have stored you can filter against and it appears as you have just one table that you have an arrangement called Table Per Hierachy (TPH)

Check this link out:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

It refers to an `OfType<T>()` method which might do your bidding.

EDIT(Corrected to working example)

With a usage something like :

```
var rootItems = context.Items.OfType<BaseItem>().Except(context.Items.OfType<ChildItem>());
```

Just the root items are pulled back in a TPH scenario.

SQL:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Except1].[Discriminator] AS [C2], 
[Except1].[Id] AS [C3], 
[Except1].[Name] AS [C4], 
[Except1].[Parent_Id] AS [C5]
FROM  (SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Parent_Id] AS [Parent_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[BaseItems] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'ChildItem',N'BaseItem')
EXCEPT
    SELECT 
    N'ChildItem' AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[Parent_Id] AS [Parent_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[BaseItems] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE [Extent2].[Discriminator] = N'ChildItem') AS [Except1]}
```

Comment: TPH, TPT... Doesn't make a difference. Already discovered how to move to TPT but the problem still remains that I don't want to select all base items. Just the root items. OfType<BaseItem> still results in all, since they're all technically of type BaseItem. (Inherited or not.)

Comment: Got you!  I am a little confused as to why you cant just query the Items collection (the collection of all the roots)? What do your DbSets look like?

Comment: I added the DBContext and DBSet definition above. The problem is that I can have a lot of records in the database. db.Items would return both BaseItem and ChildItem records while I only need the BaseItem records. Things become even more complex because I have more classes/tables that inherit from either BaseItem or ChildItem.

Comment: Worked through and confirmed retrieving just the root items with a simple case.

Comment: I think it might be shortened to `context.Items.Except(context.Items.OfType<ChildItem>());` since they're all of the BaseItem class. (Testing: Yes, it works!)
Best of all, it selects ALL root items, IE, anything derived from BaseItem but not ChildItem. Which is what I need.